# Can we reopen this? "How to deal with a colleague being rude to the customer during meetings?"

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[How to deal with a colleague being rude to the customer during meetings?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/87501/how-to-deal-with-a-colleague-being-rude-to-the-customer-during-meetings)

Closed because: "Questions require a goal that we can address. Rather than explaining the difficulties of your situation, explain what you want to do to make it better."

The goal seems to be to deal with a colleague being rude to the customer during meetings. They want to make the situation better by less rudeness, confronting the colleague, assuaging the customer's concerns, etc.

Comment: Voted to reopen.

Comment: It's a bit broad but seems answerable.

Comment: Part of the question has been removed for some reason. It used to say "This issue has already been addressed with my manager, who will deal with it." Given that actually happened, I don't see what answerable question remains.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I agree with you;  I cannot see an answerable question either.  Looks like its been reopened anyway.  The power of the community...

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to ask it in "How to keep the customer amiable when a colleague is rude to them and how to address the colleague behavior to ensure decreased rudeness in the future?  Those at least are two goals instead of a general situation...just a thought...

Comment: @mutt I guess, I just personally am really not finding a lot of difficulty in understanding this question.

Comment: The question understanding is fine, it's just worded open ended.  I was responding to Joe's comment as adding what resolution there is desired scopes the goal of the question.  You could slap your colleague which would certainly "stop them" but not productive...what is the end goal?  Regardless whatever everyone wants is fine :)

Comment: @djechlin You don't need to edit the title. One of the moderators will tag it status-completed.

Comment: @MaskedMan there's a bunch in the sidebar that aren't, and one that does the title edit.

Comment: Right then you should consider fixing or reporting those.

Comment: @MaskedMan so should you? lol

Comment: @MaskedMan editing the title is fine.  The status-complete tag is really intended for bug reports and feature requests.  For reopening (or closing) a question, editing the title is probably better -- after all, the question might bet closed (or reopened) again in the future, at which point the status tag is wrong.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Ok, then that was a mistake on my part. I saw moderators put that tag on a number of such questions so I had assumed that was the right approach.

Comment: @MaskedMan no worries; it got that way over time and, now that it's clear that we have more than a few of these, I'm trying to apply course correction.  I understand how flaggers got the idea that this is the preferred method.